# How to generate non-random points based on a certain density

Tags: python, point

I have a certain function, let's say `f(x) = sin(πx)` on the domain `[0,1]`. I would like to place `N` points in this domain such that their local density is based on the magnitude of `f(x)`, in a *non-random* fashion. A picture of what I'm trying to do is given below.

[image]

So larger magnitude = more points. Is there a name for algorithms that accomplish this? The code i'm using now is

```py
x = np.linspace(0,0.5,int((n+2)/2))
x = 1/(0.1+np.sin(np.pi * x))
x = np.cumsum(x)

x = np.interp(x, (np.min(x), np.max(x)), (0,0.5))
y = x[0:int((n+2)/2)-1]
x = np.concatenate((x, 1-y))

x = np.sort(x)
```

But this seems very inefficient, and I need to mirror the points at `x=0.5` for the points to be centered symmetrically. Additionally, the density is not exactly proportional to the magnitude of `f(x)` now.

Comment: [curvature based sampling](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167839617301462) looks interesting and might be helpful here

Answer (score 3):

That's a very nice question! The only thing that comes to my mind that is similar to what you want to get is Rejection Sampling which is a technique to sample from an arbitrary distribution, which is also related to the Metropolis algorithm and other Monte-Carlo algos.

There's a nice answer to this question. The idea is to set a desired number of samples `n_samples` (keep it odd, since we want 0.5 to be sampled and result to by symmetric).
The algorithm starts from 0.5 and samples the next point such that the area of the sine curve `sin(pi*x)` between 0.5 and that point is equal to `1 / (floor(n_samples / 2))` - that is we want to sample the next point such that the area below the curve is as stated. Then, the next point is picked iteratively following the same rule - the area below the previous point and the next point is exactly `1 / (floor(n_samples / 2))`.
Finally, we mirror the results we obtained in `(0.5,1]` to sample in [0,0.5) and add 0.5 to the sampling.

Here's an implementation:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_samples = 2*20
h_n_samples = n_samples//2

def next_sample(x):
    return np.arccos(np.cos(np.pi * x) - 1 / h_n_samples)/np.pi

samples = []
x = np.arccos(-1 / h_n_samples) / np.pi  # init
samples.append(x)
while next_sample(x) < 1:
    x = next_sample(x)
    samples.append(x)
#Mirroring w.r.t 0.5:
samples_mirrored = [1-x for x in samples]
samples += [0.5] + samples_mirrored

#Plot results:
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (8, 8)
plt.scatter(samples, np.sin(np.pi*np.array(samples)))
plt.show()
```

And here's the result:

[image]

Since we preserve the area under the curve between 2 samples we will essentially obtain a sampling which is proportional to the density.